# Can I do a clean install on HP desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm about to buy a Pavilion HPE H8, that is on sale right now. It comes with Windows 8, and I would like to get ride of it. Is it possible to do a reformat/clean install with a Windows 7 DVD that I bought for my previous computer.

I've done clean installs on custom builts, but never on a pre-built. I heard that HP makes it difficult to do so. I just don't want to buy this dekstop if I can't downgrade to Windows 7.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Depends on the type of `Windows 7` license you purchased.  If the license is already in use you will have problems activating it on the new pc.

Comment: There is a possibility of downgrading from Windows 8 to 7 without any problems(you have license to win8 that works for win7 too). Try to google how to downgrade.

Comment: I'ld like to do a clean install instead of a downgrade, since I don't want all the bloatware (to me anyways...) that is bundled with pre-builts. Thanks for the tips on the downgrade!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to disable **Secure Boot** from the BIOS/UEFI settings and after that you can boot from the DVD and install Win7 as usual. Before you start ensure you have Win7 drivers available, and optionally you might want to create any recovery media as recommended by HP or image your drive so you can restore Win8 if required.

Comment: You're welcome, and BTW I've only addressed the installation aspect. Don't forget to keep in mind licensing issues as stated by the commenters above.